# distributing tables over multiple harddrives

Tags: performance, raid, hard-drive

Is there a performance improvement when I distribute database tables over different harddrives?

I need to access many different schemas at the same time and I was wondering if adding more harddrives would significantly improve performance when I distribute the tables over the different harddrives.

So let's say I have **100 tables and 1 harddrive** vs **100 tables and 10 harddrives**. 
Would this make a difference? Or am I better off linking the harddrives in a RAID configuration?

Comment: RAID-10 with SSD cache and be done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More harddrives generally do increase the theoretical IO performance. By what *useful amount* differs greatly on the method. In many real world applications (and for smaller numbers of disks) the increase in IO performance is not even close to linear.

Scenarios where more disks don't increase the performance are for example those where the limits of the (RAID) controller are reached. 10 high end SSD's on a older or cheap (RAID) controller will often result in the controller being the limiting factor rather than the disk.  [RAID levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels) are also at least as much about providing data protection as they are about performance.
2 disks in RAID 1 (mirroring) gives you zero additional write performance, but on a good controller will still double the read performance.

Manually assigning (virtual) disks to certain tasks provides guaranteed IO paths for those tasks allowing for a certain level concurrency of those tasks and is for example something database administrators like to do. Of course that limits the peak performance of each individual tasks as well. And with any (manual) tuning, getting it wrong can greatly hinder performance :)

A single enterprise 15k SAS spinning disk offers typically about 200-250 IOPS (IO Operations Per Second). Simply put 10 disks will offer ten times that.

If in your example one table is predominantly being used, assigning that table to 1 disk and having the other 99 tables on the other remaining disks has no measurable benefit, effectively you would still be limited to about 200 IOPS. In that scenario having all 100 tables on a single RAID 10 volume though, you would have all 10 disks and thus 2000+ IOPS for read operations and 1000 IOPS (effective the resources half the disks, 5 disks, due to the mirroring) for write operations... a great increase.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing I/O throughput will almost always increase performance.  However, there is no magic formula for how many hard drives should be used for a certain number of tables or databases.  There are too many factors to consider: data size, schema design, write or read heavy, number of queries, etc.

Aside from adding additional hardware it always helps to analyse your table structures and the most common queries being ran against your databases.  Sometimes just adding an index for commonly requested data will do wonders that not even throwing more hardware at will do.

Answer (score 1):

Besides increasing the number of physical disks, you need to modify Oracle to run more parallel processes.  I do this with:

```
NAME                           CURRENT_MEMORY_VALUE
------------------------------ ---------------------
parallel_max_servers           32
parallel_min_servers           8
parallel_servers_target        32
parallel_threads_per_cpu       4
```

The commands to make these changes are:

```
alter system set PARALLEL_MIN_SERVERS=8 scope=memory;          <== RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_MIN_SERVERS=8 scope=spfile sid='*';  <== RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS=32 scope=memory;          <== RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS=32 scope=spfile sid='*';  <== RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_SERVERS_TARGET=32 scope=memory;          <== RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_SERVERS_TARGET=32 scope=spfile sid='*';  <== RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU=4 scope=memory;          <== RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU=4 scope=spfile sid='*';  <== RAC

alter system set PARALLEL_MIN_SERVERS=8 scope=both;          <== NON RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS=32 scope=both;          <== NON RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_SERVERS_TARGET=32 scope=both;          <== NON RAC
alter system set PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU=4 scope=both;          <== NON RAC
```

Comment: How will this exactly help me? Will it increase throughput?